# React Native Fetch on Android returns Network request failed

Tags: android, reactjs, http, networking, native

I am building a React Native mobile application that is using a Laravel backend, currently running on localhost:8000. When making a fetch request from an Android device to my server, my application gets the following error logs:

[image]

My code is below:

```
export default class App extends Component {
 login() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/establishments/get')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log('success!');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => this.login()}>
        <Text>Sign In</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

When I copy and paste the exact route into my browser, the server responds successfully and completely as expected. I believe it is an issue with network permissions from my application? I have only just began learning React Native a week ago and would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: I have also tried adding axios to my React Native application and using axios.get(...) and I get an identical error log as when using fetch, shown in the above image.

Answer (score 2):

iOS runs in a simulator while Android runs in an emulator.
Emulator emulates a real device, while simulator only imitates a device.
Therefore localhost on Android points to the emulated Android device instead  of the machine where your server runs.
You should change localhost in yours request paths with the IP address of your machine.

More details at: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404#issuecomment-267303151

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that 127.0.0.1 or localhost will point to the emulator itself in your computer where the server is currently running. Try replacing 127.0.0.1 / localhost with 10.0.2.2 if you are on AVD or 10.0.3.2 if you are on Genymotion or with your computer's actual IP address. In addition, you should also make sure that your android app can use internet. You can do that by adding

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify. I am using the 'npm start' command from my terminal, and deploying to my physical device (Galaxy S8+).

Comment: can you access internet, on your phone and are you in the same network as your computer?

Comment: Yes I am on the same WiFi as my laptop, on my phone.

Comment: Do you have this on android manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to enable internet?

Comment: Do you know where the AndroidManifest.xml is located?

Comment: That might be it. It's in your-project-name/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. Add it after your `<manifest>` tag.

Comment: Hmm.. now I'm sort of confused. I created my project using the following terminal command: create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
and I do not have an android directory in my project at all.

Comment: Ah i see. So you are using expo for your app. I think it might be the case that the code is actually not in the computer but somewhere else and thus could not access your local server. Try putting your server somewhere like heroku and I think your app should be able to access it.

Comment: Yes, sorry once again for not specifying. And thank you. I am going to try that now with Heroku. I truly appreciate your time D-reaper!! :D

Answer (score 1):

**Founded solution for Laravel and react native (Physical device)**

1. open cmd run `ipconfig` copy ipv4 address for example my ipv4 address is 192.168.43.235
2. Connect same network for laptop and physical device or open hotspot and connect same network
3. Now run command start laravel backend `php artisan serve --host=192.168.43.235 --port=8000`
4. change api url from react native api service

apiServise.js

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const api_url = 'http://192.168.43.235:8000';
    
    export const getCategories = request =>
  axios
    .get(api_url + '/api/categories', {
      params: request || {},
    })
    .then(response => response.data);
```

homescreen.js

```
import {getCategories} from '../services/ApiService';

async fetchCategories() {
    await getCategories()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          dataCategories: response
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

1. Now run command start react native app `react-native run-android`

that is all...now api request working fine.

Answer (score -2):

Change  http://localhost:8000/api/establishments/get localhost with, which can your emulator reach generally 10.0.2.2 ;) have phun.