# Getting a CORS issue when posting data from frontend(React)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

I'm posting data from react to spring boot backend using axios. Please refer the below react code.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    alert( "Username "+ username + " Password "+password);
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/sign-up',{
        username:username,
        password:password})
};
```

Below is my spring code.
@PostMapping("/sign-up")
public String signUp(@RequestBody User user) {

```
    if(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername())==null) {
        Set<Role> roles= new HashSet<>();
        Role role= roleRepository.findByName("USER");
        roles.add(role);
        user.setRoles(roles);
        user.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "Success";
    }
    else{
        return "Username Already Exsist";
    }
}
```

When I post data from front end i'm getting below response in the browser console.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/sign-up' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:8080/sign-up net::ERR_FAILED
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

I've inserted following line in the controller of the spring boot.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
```

But the above solution didn't work. I suspect during the post call option call is happening to check the resource and in that case only this cors issue is occuring. Appreciate any input to this issue.

Comment: I'm able to overcome this cors issue. I've posted the answer for any future need.

Comment: Maybe helpful => https://stackoverflow.com/a/62542731/11302100

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue recently.

I got a first step further by removing spring-boot-starter-security from my POM temporarily, because it was blocking the call giving unauthorized. So I figured out that that was my problem. I had to configure CORS for Spring security and then I got it to work. Apologies for the vague answer, but I hope it can help you look in another direction that could help you.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution for the above problem. This cors issue is coming when there is a communication happening between different domains. So I have added below line in the configure() method of SecurityConfig class.

```
 http.cors();
```

Then I have implemented the following CustomCorsFilter class.
@Component
public class CustomCorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Allow, authorization, content-type, xsrf-token");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(httpServletRequest.getMethod())) {
            httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Now there is no cors issue.